Databricks access for users - terraform deployments
I have deployed the Databricks worksapces (USING SPN) with the terraform in dedicated RG. This RG has inhereted AD group and RBAC assigned as owner.
I would expect that all the members of that AD group would have had the access to the workspace but they get the error below.
I can only fix this if I manually add them from the workspaces settings. What could be the issue that they dont have the access to workspace automatically. My user and SPN are automatically added


Is this an Enterprise account or a personal account using providers like Gmail?

Enterprise account


I would expect that all the members of that AD group would have had the access to the workspace but they get the error below.

If you provide the Owner role to the Azure AD group at the resource group level, the Azure AD group won't sync to the Databricks workspace
To provide access to Databricks workspace logins, you need to create a group inside the workspace and add the users to the group.
Here is the terraform code to create a Group and add the users to group in data bricks workspace.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "158b8345-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f"
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = "https://adb-853311726490768.8.azuredatabricks.net"
  token = "dapi8491c8c713262239abd37c1c6f5d5f85-3"
}

resource "databricks_group" "this" {
  display_name               = "workspacelogins"
  allow_cluster_create       = true
  allow_instance_pool_create = true

}

resource "databricks_user" "me" {
  user_name = "databricksadmin@abc.com"
}

resource "databricks_group_member" "admins" {
  group_id  = databricks_group.this.id
  member_id = databricks_user.me.id
}

Once you create a group and then enable the workspace login access to the group by navigating Workspace settings > Identity and access > Groups.

After enabling the workspace access to the group, all the users inside the group can be able to access to the workspace.
Reference:  databricks_permission_assignment Resource

after deployement of the databricks,"launch workspace" will autoamtically add them. Why I could not do at first was that I shared url to my colleague, which should not happen for the first time.

When you create a workspace, your account will be automatically added, but not other accounts; for others, you must add them manually or you can use terraform

as I said above, when you go to azure protal and then dataricks resoruce, by clicking the launch workspace will automatically add people who are assigned to that worksapce

Do you mean that when someone launches a workspace from the portal by going to Azure Portal > Datarick's workspace, they are automatically added? I

yes, only when they have RBAC assigned

Ok, If you want to access workspace without role, you need to add the user in workstation before login.

I hope this helps to resolve your query?
